# Types of volume on an iPhone, iPod and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudiosession, mpmusicplayercontroller

When I set the volume of iPhone programatically using `[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]` I can still listen to the audio.

Are there multiple volume's on an iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

indeed there is, there are levels for phone, mp3/ipod playback and ringer. each changable by the user at the time of usage by the buttons.

Comment: Also, the headphone and speaker jack have a different volume settings, and if the iOS device can tell one pair of headphones apart from another pair (requires a proprietary chip in the headphones) then that pair will have it's own volume.

Comment: "sound effects" volume is another one?